# Button not changing state in react js based on api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jsx

I have this page which shows a single post and I have a like button. if the post is liked, when the user clicks the button, it changes its state to unlike button, but if the post is not liked, then the like is getting registered and the id is getting pushed on to the array, but the button state is not getting updated and I have to reload the page to see the page. Can someone tell me how to resolve this issue?

This is the code:

```
    const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false)

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    function likePosts(post, user) {
        post.likes.push({ id: user });
        setData(post);
        axiosInstance.post('api/posts/' + post.slug + '/like/');
        window.location.reload()
    }

    function unlikePosts(post, user) {
        console.log('unliked the post');
        data.likes = data.likes.filter(x => x.id !== user);
        setData(data);
        return (
            axiosInstance.delete('api/posts/' + post.slug + '/like/')
        )
    }
```

For the button:

```
{data.likes && data.likes.find(x => x.id === user) ?
        (<FavoriteRoundedIcon style={{ color: "red" }}
            onClick={() => {
                unlikePosts(data, user)
                setLiked(() => liked === false)
            }   
        }
        />)
        : (<FavoriteBorderRoundedIcon
               onClick={() => {
               likePosts(data, user)
               setLiked(() => liked === true)
               }
        }
        />)
    }
```

Thanks and please do ask if more details are needed.

Comment: You shouldn't mutate the state directly; use `setData`.

Comment: Hey, can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I cannot really test your code, but you are assigning to `data.likes` which shouldn't be done. Also, what is `data` supposed to be? Your initial state is an array, but it seems like you are using it as an object.

Comment: data contains all the properties of the post, So should I store it in another variable and work with it?

Comment: Yes, so it should be an object (you are using `useState([])`). You can change it with something like `setData(data => {...data, likes: data.likes.filter(...)})`. May I ask, what is `setLiked(() => liked === false)` supposed to do? Why not `setLiked(false)`?

Comment: Oh.okay, Thank you, I will try like that. setLiked(false) didn't work, so I was like changing it and seeing whether I could somehow make it work.

Comment: You are also mutating the state directly here: `post.likes.push(...)`. I think the best way would be to use console logging or React DevTools to debug your code, as it's hard to help if I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Oh.okay, I will try it, but can you see if there are any errors with the logic ?

Comment: Also if it isn't an array, can I push the id inside the object when the user likes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223592/discussion-between-iz-and-danny).

Comment: everything @iz_ has said is right.  Do you want me to post a revised code example, or are you good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @iz_ pointed out in the comments, your main problem is that you are directly mutating state rather than calling a `setState` function.

I'm renaming `data` to `post` for clarity since you have said that this is an object representing the data for one post.

```
const [post, setPost] = useState(initialPost);
```

You don't need to use `liked` as a state because we can already access this information from the `post` data by seeing if our user is in the `post.likes` array or not.  This allows us to have a "single source of truth" and we only need to make updates in one place.

```
const isLiked = post.likes.some((like) => like.id === user.id);
```

I'm confused about the `likes` array.  It seems like an array of objects which are just `{id: number}`, in which case you should just have an array of ids of the users who liked the post.  But maybe there are other properties in the object (like a username or timestamp).

When designing a component for something complex like a blog post, you want to break out little pieces that you can use in other places of your app.  We can define a `LikeButton` that shows our heart.  This is a "presentation" component that doesn't handle any logic.  All it needs to know is whether the post `isLiked` and what to do `onClick`.

```
export const LikeButton = ({ isLiked, onClick }) => {
  const Icon = isLiked ? FavoriteRoundedIcon: FavoriteBorderRoundedIcon;
  return (
    <Icon
      style={{ color: isLiked ? "red" : "gray" }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
};
```

A lot of our logic regarding liking and unliking could potentially be broken out into some sort of `usePostLike` hook, but I haven't fully optimized this because I don't know what your API is doing and how we should respond to the response that we get.

When a user clicks the like button we want the changes to be reflected in the UI immediately, so we call `setPost` and add or remove the current user from the `likes` array.  We have to set the state with a new object, so we copy all of the post properties that are not changing with the spread operator `...post` and then override the `likes` property with an edited version.  `filter()` and `concat()` are both safe array functions which return a new copy of the array.

We also need to call the API to post the changes.  You are using the same url in both the "like" and "unlike" scenarios, so instead of calling `axios.post` and `axios.delete`, we can call the generalized function `axios.request` and pass the method name `'post'` or `'delete'` as an argument to the `config` object. [[axios docs]](https://github.com/axios/axios)  We could probably combine our two `setPost` calls in a similar way and change `likePost()` and `unlikePost()` into one `toggleLikePost()` function.  But for now, here's what I've got:

```
export const Post = ({ initialPost, user }) => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState(initialPost);

  const isLiked = post.likes.some((like) => like.id === user.id);

  function likePost() {
    console.log("liked the post");
    // immediately update local state to reflect changes
    setPost({
      ...post,
      likes: post.likes.concat({ id: user.id })
    });
    // push changes to API
    apiUpdateLike("post");
  }

  function unlikePost() {
    console.log("unliked the post");
    // immediately update local state to reflect changes
    setPost({
      ...post,
      likes: post.likes.filter((like) => like.id !== user.id)
    });
    // push changes to API
    apiUpdateLike("delete");
  }

  // generalize like and unlike actions by passing method name 'post' or 'delete'
  async function apiUpdateLike(method) {
    try {
      // send request to API
      await axiosInstance.request("api/posts/" + post.slug + "/like/", { method });
      // handle API response somehow, but not with window.location.reload()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  function onClickLike() {
    if (isLiked) {
      unlikePost();
    } else {
      likePost();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{post.title}</h2>
      <div>{post.likes.length} Likes</div>
      <LikeButton onClick={onClickLike} isLiked={isLiked} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64526349-0piih?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I will try this way  :)

Comment: Hey @Linda, I tried this, but I am getting an error in this line, `const isLiked = post.likes.some((like) => like.id === user.id);` and this is the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'likes' of undefined`. Can you please look into it?
and as you said, the likes array contains the id and username of users.

Comment: This is my `console.log(post)` looks like `id: 152
likes: []
post_date: "2020-10-25T09:21:14.531431+01:00"
postimage_set: (2) [{…}, {…}]
display_pic: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/pimage/1/profile_pic_C68UK9J.png"
slug: "just-checking-multiple-upload"
title: "Just checking multiple upload!"
user: "testuser12"
`
but when I try `console.log(post.likes)` it throws this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'likes' of undefined`. Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't show any error and like and unlike works if I change the function like this `const isLiked = post && post.likes && post.likes.some((like) => like.id === user.id);` but the problem is when I reload the page, the button is in unliked state even if the user has already liked the post.

Comment: Re: TypeError, it might be that we are accessing it too early before `post` exists?  `post` would be the object that is `undefined` in that error.  I assumed the post was already loaded, which is why I was using `initialPost`.  Idk but you can use optional chaining `const isLiked = post?.likes.some((like) => like.id === user?.id);`

Comment: When you refresh the page all our local states get reset.  But you sent the changes to the API, so when you refresh you should be getting updated data from the API that shows that they have liked it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try that .:)